Only show references to my files in a Python exception traceback
When I have an error in a Python script, the traceback output references a number of "core" python files.
Example:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File
~\App\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in
compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)
...

It would be helpful to condense this and only see references to my files - where the problem will be.
Is there a way to have the Traceback output ignore references to "core files", or only show references to files in my script folders?

The traceback module gives you access to the traceback.
